# Using Jena Api in Java Web... Unknown Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, owl, jena

Did anyone encountered this exception while using Jena in Java Web Application... Please Kindly help me ..

Here is my servlet code

```
package com.mycompany.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class GreetingServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/GreetingServlet")
public class GreetingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public GreetingServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String SOURCE ="file:E:\\healthcare.owl";

        OntModel base =  ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
        base.read( SOURCE );


        for (Iterator<OntClass> i = base.listClasses(); i.hasNext(); ) 
        {

        OntClass c = i.next();              

        //System.out.println( "Class" + c.getLocalName());

        }
    }

    }
```

Exception is
HTTP Status 500 -

---

type Exception report

message

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.mycompany.servlet.GreetingServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.11 logs.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model
```

That means that tomcat can't find the Jena libraries. Make sure you have all the right jars in  the right place.

Comment: changing the code won't do anything (unless you remove the Jena dependencies). You need to go look in that framework's documentation too see which jar files you need to include in your deployment.

Comment: I have already placed all my jena jar files in application build path. But the exception still presents.. whatelse do I need

Comment: you need those jars somewhere where apache can find them. either they must be bundled into what you deploy, or be placed somewhere global in tomcat's directories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy each of the `*.jar` files from `$JENA/lib` (where `$JENA` is the directory you installed your local installation of Jena into) to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your servlet application.

Answer (score 0):

just copy the jena jars declared on the build path project to the lib directory of tomcat, in my case it is located at

> C:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib

Comment: I faced the same issue and this was the solution for me.

Comment: I feel confusing to put servlet dependencies in the tomcat installation, but ok it's an answer.

Comment: it doesn't work in my case by adding them to web-INF/lib, so I just maked the jars directly accessed by tomcat, that is why I followed this solution.